# How to fix Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

When I execute the code below I get Error Code: 29. File '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Gefle442/csv/places.csv' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

```
USE Gefle442;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'jim'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'x';
GRANT ALL ON games.* TO 'jim'@'localhost';
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
SET GLOBAL local_infile = "ON";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gamestats;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS games;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS arenas;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS standings;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS formations;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS competitions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS teams;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS places;


CREATE TABLE places (
    ID integer(5) unique not null,
    Place varchar(40),
    Municipality varchar(40),
    Country varchar(40),
    Continent varchar(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
ENGINE INNODB
CHARSET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_swedish_ci
;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Gefle442/csv/places.csv'
INTO TABLE places
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    TERMINATED BY ','
LINES
    TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
;
```

I've tried using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE which gives me Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

Grateful for any help and let me know if you want me to provide more detail.

Comment: The use of `LOAD DATA INFILE` must be allowed in the configuration of the DB server.

Comment: Thx, where do I do that?

Comment: You read that in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: From what I could gather I'm supposed to put
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv=""

in my.conf.

I restarted MySQL Database server through Xampp och restarted MySql Workbench. Same error message

Comment: Make sure to read the entire documentation, because there are several implications on LOAD DATA INFILE revolving around having access to the files/locations. The path you specified is absolute, so can the DB server access this file directly? Is it on the DB server machine?

Comment: The csv-file is on my computer, within the Xampp-folder which is set to "Everyone can read and write". So I can't see any restriction there.

Comment: bro did u know the solution ? because i have .dat file and i want to upload it to my table using this command LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "employee.dat"  INTO TABLE employee  FIELDS ENCLOSED BY "\"" TERMINATED BY ",";

Answer (score 0):

Solved now. Allowed read access to all files in Xampp folder by choosing the setting "Use for included objects" (don't know exactly what it's called in English) on the Xampp parent folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).